# Rich Data Table Filter on date column

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, richfaces, jsf-2.2

I have a rich data table which i want to filter based on date selected above data table. I have written`<rich:column filterType="custom" filterExpression="#{fn:filterBaseOnExpiryType(resultValue.endDate);}">` and I have tried adding `filterMethod="#{bean.filterMethod}"` still when data table displays rows it is not invoking filter method which is binded in bean. Is there any other work around to invoke filter with that current record date as input parameter

Comment: I'm assuming you're using RichFaces 3. Why do you need both `filterExpression` and `filterMethod`? They do the same thing.

Comment: @Makhiel I am using version 4.3. I don't want both, but when I use filter expression because it is searching for property in the backing bean method is not getting invoked. Even though I create a method with getXXXX and bind XXXX to filterExpression I needed the current value to be passed to the method and I am not able to pass the current value to the method because of getXXXX. Looks like filterMethod is not available in version 4.3

Comment: No, RichFaces 4 doesn't have `filterMethod`, where is `fn:filterBaseOnExpiryType` from? That doesn't look like a standard function.

Comment: @Makhiel Yes, RichFaces4 doesnt have filterMethod(i was refering to 3.3 earlier, thanks) and filterBaseOnExpiryType is not actual method that is dummy method i have used for putting my question. Thanks for the info.